# Why Salesforce has changeEvent version of object in org(even though it is not enabled)

Tags: object, change-data-capture

I was browsing my org, and found that changeEvent type of object is available, whereas I did not have it enabled for any object. Doesn't it make available if and only if it is enabled(like share object).

Is there any specific reason for that?

> Update: Adding screenshots

**CDC is not enabled for any objects:**
[image: CDC is not enabled]

**Available CDC object in my org:**
[image: Available CDC objects in my org]

Comment: can you give some more info - like screenshot or anything?

Comment: @salesforce-sas Added screenshots. Pls let me know if more details required.

Answer (score 0):

Change Event objects are available by default in any Salesforce Org for applicable standard objects and all custom objects. Every time you create a new custom object, it also creates an associated change event object for the same.

Only when you select an object from Setup, you are able to get notifications for those selected objects. This is from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_object_support.htm):

> Change events are available for all custom objects defined in your Salesforce org and a subset of standard objects.

As for the reason I would think that is very specific to why/how it was designed that way.

Comment: Yes I read that document and assumed that, when I do enable then only I will have the ChangeEvent object(which includes all custom objects). As far as, current thing seems to have additional load on org(if not used these events). Sharing object create only when it is required. Hence I would like to know is there really any specific need/limitation which yielded with current design. Pls ignore if my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: Any design/need cannot be really answered by us if not publicly documented. That will be best answered by Salesforce, I am just not sure if you can get that answer.